# How to enable UMA for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpgpu

I am using CUDA 8 and tensorflow. I am trying to how I can enable UMA for so that tensorflow can make use of it.

Any idea if i need to set any environment variable? I don't see any documentation around this

Comment: TF doesn't support it.

Comment: Do you know if its planned in future?

Comment: Don't believe so. TensorFlow already has a mechanism to utilize memory of all GPUs and exchange data between them